# Error when trying to compile java files in project with Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, protocol-buffers

I'm currently working on a project which uses the Protocol Buffers library.

At the moment I'm trying to produce a jar file. Whilst this is fine, it doesn't run. When I try compiling each of the classes inside the project via this method (I am using a Macbook Air):

```
bash: find . -iname "*.java" > sources.txt
bash: java @sources.txt
```

However, this fails, and prints out the following message (shortened obviously):

```
./protobuf/build/java/intergroup/board/Board.java:9: error: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
  com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite registry) {
                     ^

./protobuf/build/java/intergroup/board/Board.java:13: error: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
  com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
                     ^

./protobuf/build/java/intergroup/board/Board.java:7769: error: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist private static final 
com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor

... //Repeats a good number of times for other Protocol Buffer classes
```

Would this be a reason why the jar file does not work? I am using Eclipse, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compile java files to class files using bash, use Eclipse instead. It will take longer if you use this method than your method and it will run just fine. This is why using IDE or (Integrated Development Environment) to create and compile applications without bashes or commands.

**Note: The previous answer is not correct from my understanding today after reading this again.**

**Another Note: Why are you using bash?**